# Sharing an Excel with Typescript functions

Tags: excel, typescript, office365, share

I have an Excel with several buttons, running with Typescripts saved on my Onedrive. Now I want my colleagues using the workbook and its functions. I've shared the Excel workbook and gave read and write access to the people in the team.
But, nobody can use the buttons in the workbook. At first they received a message read-only, now they can see write but no progress...

Can somebody advise where I can find guidelines on sharing such a workbook? As the final idea is work with the Excel via O365 on a browser...

Thanks!

I shared the document, gave full read and write permissions to workbook and scripts.